# Catching an unknown exception the caused by a native library (JNI) used in SDK

Tags: java, android, exception, java-native-interface

I'm using third party SDK which uses some native libraries with `System.loadLibrary` using `JNI`.
The problem is that the SDK is not reliable and it's keep crashing, the crash is not coming from the SDK java code but from the native libraries, I'm not able to figure out what may cause the error, furthermore it crashes in different scenarios. 
How can I catch an exception coming from native libraries without actually knowing their type?

Comment: share your stack trace.

Comment: Have you installed NDK? because JNI lib, needs NDK

Comment: Everything needed installed... the app is working!  unfortunately I can't share the stack trace since the SDK is kind of for private use.